# DELETE and UPDATE with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am building gallery with categories and having problem with this subject.

Only 2 tables.
1st table has categories

Second table has photos data.
Second table has category_id from 1st table.
Pretty simple...

now when i delete the category i would like to update 2nd table with category_id = NULL ot = ''.
Is it possible ?

I tried using triggers but no success yet. getting syntax errors...

```
$sql = "
CREATE TRIGGER update_gal_items AFTER DELETE ON gallery_category
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_category='' WHERE photo_category=$id;
END
";
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Use foreign key constraint on category_id with UPDATE to NULL

Comment: My problem was using multiple queries one after another.
thats why i tried triggers. 

there is no problem to update or delete separatly. 

i want a DELETE action trigger UPDATE in another TABLE

Comment: Anyways, your trigger syntax is wrong. You cant have php variables inside the trigger. Trigger is defined at mysql server side itself

Comment: In a delete trigger I would expect to see reference to OLD. values.

Comment: Thats another problem i guess. How do i let the trigger now what id should it use to remove the row i need ?

Comment: 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html clearly there are no NEW. values in a delete trigger.

Comment: `$sql = "
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_gal_items AFTER DELETE ON gallery_category
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_category=NULL WHERE photo_category=OLD.category_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
"; `

still getting syntax error. 
string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER update_gal_items AFTER DELETE ON gallery_category ' at line 1"

Comment: Why not delete the corresponding row in gallery_photos too?

Comment: cause i want to give the option to reuse the same photos for diffrent category.

Comment: @PavelNasonov check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353451/2469308

Answer (score 2):

You should rather apply [Foreign key constraint:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

```
ALTER TABLE gallery_photos
ADD FOREIGN KEY (photo_category) REFERENCES gallery_category(category_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

**Note** that I am assuming `category_id` as field name in your parent table (gallery_category).

Now, if you still want to use [Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html), then define the following trigger on your `gallery_category` table:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS gallery_category_delete_trigger //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER gallery_category_delete_trigger 
    AFTER DELETE ON gallery_category  
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

      UPDATE gallery_photos 
         SET photo_category = NULL
      WHERE photo_category = OLD.category_id;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @PavelNasonov yes it is a username to DB. But I generally keep it to `root@localhost`, to avoid issues when other sessions/users trying to access DB and value does not auto update

Comment: well there is kinda movement getting new error in phpmyadmin

`You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)`

Comment: @PavelNasonov it seems like you have permission issues! You most likely dont have permissions to create new triggers

Comment: it actually doesnt matter if to use trigger or something else. 

is there any other way it can be achived ?

Comment: @PavelNasonov Three ways that I can think of: Foreign keys, Triggers, and making changes to your application code. First two requires editing permissions at MySQL server side. Last one requires you to code the following steps: Delete the `category_id` from parent table. Update to set null for all the rows matching the `category_id` in the child table.

Comment: i actually wated the 3rd option when i started :) 
after google search i ended up trying to appy triggers.

Comment: @PavelNasonov SO, where are you stuck in your 3rd option ?

Answer (score 0):

Well running to diffrent queries solves the problem...

```
global $conn;
if( isset( $_POST['cat_id'] ) ) {
  $id = (int)$_POST['cat_id'];
}
$sql = "UPDATE `gallery_photos` SET `photo_category` = '' WHERE `photo_category` = ?";
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt1->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt1->execute();
if (! $stmt1) {
       $this->log->error ( "Mysqli prepare error: " . mysqli_error ( $conn ) );
       throw new MysqliExecuteException ( "Mysqli error: " . mysqli_error ( $conn ) );
 }

$sql_n = "DELETE FROM `gallery_category` WHERE `category_id` = '$id'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_n);
$stmt->execute();
if (! $stmt) {
       $this->log->error ( "Mysqli prepare error: " . mysqli_error ( $conn ) );
       throw new MysqliExecuteException ( "Mysqli error: " . mysqli_error ( $conn ) );
 }
```

Thanks everyone for their time. :)

Comment: Please parameterize these queries. This is very much open to SQL injection. If you cant move to parametrized queries, atleast **use single quotes** around `$id` and `(int)` typecasting for the `$id` (assuming it to be an integer field). Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: so i guess your answer does not match your question !!! what you wanted was to delete the rows of table2 that referred to the table1 row you deleted !

Comment: @YvesLeBorg no i wanter to update rows in the A after i delete a row in table B